# Showing submitted results from php/mysql drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm hoping for a simple solution to my ever annoying problem. I have looked online and in books. I need to display results from my drop down menu. It is currently connected to the database/table and displaying the l_state as needed. All I need now is, when the state is selected, I hit submit and the information in the table is displayed below the drop down/submit button. Here is my code so far.

```
//db_connect included at top

$sql="SELECT * FROM licensing ORDER BY l_state DESC"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

  $id=$row["id"]; 
  $url=$row["l_url"]; 
  $phone=$row["l_phone"]; 
  $state=$row["l_state"];
  $sullstate=$row["l_statefull"];  
  $options.="<option value=\"$id\">".$state; 
} 


<select name="listing">

<select name="listing"><option value=0>Choose<?=$options?></option></select>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

---

So if there is anyone out there that can help me with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$options .="<option value=\"$id\">".$state ."</option>";
```

And HTML part like this

```
<select name="listing">
  <option value=0>Choose</option>
  <?php echo $options ;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the current page is submitted (or submit to a other page).

This is possible using if(isset($_POST)) or if($_REQUEST['POST']), after then you need to build your query and include the posted data in the query (make sure you use escaping for that).